# How to determine terminal cursor visibility?

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, cross-platform, ansi-escape

I am writing application on C++ that can change cursor state via ANSI sequences. I want to restore cursor visibility state after application is done.

You can easily achieve this in Windows:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

bool IsCursorVisible() {
    HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cursorInfo;
    GetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);

    return cursorInfo.bVisible;
}
```

But with Linux situation becomes different. How can I achieve the same functionality on Linux or is there any cross-platform non-lib solution?

Comment: In the two thousand pages that make up the current C++ standard there's not a single mention of something called "cursor" or its visibility whatever that means. That means that a "cross-platform" solution does not exist.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik just because it's not part of the standard library doesn't mean that there's no cross platform solution from a third party library

Comment: Correct, @AlanBirtles, except for the "non-lib solution" requested in this question.

Comment: What do you mean by `non-lib solution`?

Comment: @Philippe I mean without using libraries that are not included with the compiler.

Comment: That sounds like too strict a constraint. `ncurses` may provide what you need.

Comment: The only libraries that are included with the compiler are the ones that implement the C++ standard, no more not less. There is no "cross-platform solution", as defined here, sorry.

Comment: The code presented itself violates the "non-lib solution", as it is using the Win32 API lib.

Comment: It's an unwritten rule that apps leave the terminal in a "clean" state for each other. No colors, no bold/italic/etc. typeface, no mouse support enabled etc. If it's not the case somewhere then it likely results in incorrect display or incorrect behavior of the next app. As for the cursor, the obviously clean state is to show it. Forget about querying the state at startup, it's complicated, for no practical benefit. Just make sure to show the cursor when you quit (if you hid it at all; obviously no action needed if you didn't tamper with it).

Answer (score 1):

Some terminals (i.e., [xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) and those which copy the feature from xterm) provide an extension to [`DECRQM`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Ps-$-p.1D6D) which gives the state from [`DECTCEM`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Pm-h:Ps-=-2-5.1EC4).

That has been a feature of xterm since [2010](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_262):

> implement *ANSI and DEC request-mode control sequences*. The latter includes the xterm-specific private modes such as the mouse mode. The feature is ifdef'd with the rectangle operations since its decoding overlaps that feature.

For other terminals, consult their documentation.